# Who left the box with Lysa's letter for Luwin?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Just started re-reading *Game of Thrones*, and in it Luwin says that he found a box on his desk with a lens from Myr. Inside a hidden compartment he found a letter for Catelyn.

Who dropped off the box?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has never been answered explicitly.

But the Maester thought someone from the King's entourage must have been in Lysa's service and left the letter.

> The maester waited until the door had closed behind him before he
>   spoke. “My lord,” he said to Ned, “pardon for disturbing your rest. I
>   have been left a message.”
>
> Ned looked irritated. “Been left? By whom? Has there been a rider? I
>   was not told.”
>
> “There was no rider, my lord. Only a carved wooden box, left on a
>   table in my observatory while I napped. My servants saw no one, but it
>   must have been brought by someone in the king’s party. We have had no
>   other visitors from the south.”
> <sub>**AGOT - Catelyn II**</sub>

But since we know Lysa wrote that letter on behest of Petyr Baelish, there must have been someone in the King's Party who was tasked by either of those two to deliver the message.

It could be someone who accompanied them from King's Landing or someone disguised as a Free-rider who attached himself to King's party on the road.

Of all the known characters in King's party (The Hound, Prince Joffrey, Prince Tommen, Queen Cersei, King himself, Jaime Lannister, Princess Myrcella and Tyrion Lannister) none could be expected to be on payroll of Lady Arryn or Lord Baelish. So it must have been a literary extra, chosen for this task. Unnamed and unidentified.

Maester Luwin's assessment is very likely. If they had no riders from outside except King's party, it must have been some member of the King's party, but not someone who could be named.

**TL;DR**, no it has never been answered that who was the agent here. And it is unlikely that it will be revealed at all given the irrelevance now as the big mystery of why the letter was sent is already solved.